# Masking a BufferedImage

Tags: java, bufferedimage

How would you overlay two `BufferedImage` objects on top of each other on specific parts?

Let's say you have two `BufferedImage` objects, and you have a list of `Rectangle2D` objects. You want to overwrite the first `BufferedImage` with the second `BufferedImage` at the rectangles. How would you do this?

Comment: then how are you supposed to share your knowledge

Comment: You said you asked this question already. Why didn't you post an answer to that?

Comment: cuz i deleted it :/ i didnt post enough information

Comment: If you post an appropriately detailed and on-topic question, then you can also post an answer to it.

Comment: but i will delete this one and use the answer-your-own-question method

Comment: @Orbyfied See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer on answering your own question.

Comment: but i fixed the problem. i dont want to have to develop a context just to post an answer.

Comment: don't delete this one but stick it to a question and answer model

Comment: this is not how this community works

Comment: Who was getting mad?

Comment: nvm i was overexaggerating sorry

Comment: im just new to the community and i thought i would help by posting a solution but i dont really know how to do that so i just made a question with solution in the title

Comment: Hopefully the comments and edits have helped show you how to do it.

Comment: yes! definitely. this helped me for the future and i hope that this post helps someone

Comment: last advice: if you think that the answer fits the question, you can mark it as "accepted" . You may want to refer to [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). This in the way that qualify your answer as "the solution" to the question within this community. Hope it helps

Comment: thank you! - i need more characters to post a comment so

Answer (score 1):

You use `TexturePaint` and draw a rectangle!

First you create a output image using `BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(<width>,<height>,<colorMode>)`, then you create and get the `Graphics2D` object using `Graphics2D g = result.createGraphics()`.

Then you draw the full source image (Image1) onto the output image using `g.drawImage(<sourceImage>, null, 0, 0)`.

To overlay the `BufferedImage` we will use `TexturePaint` and the `g.fill(rect)` method;
You want to loop through all of the rectangles using a for loop like this: `for (Rectangle2D rect : rectangles)`
In the constructor for the `TexturePaint` you use the `BufferedImage.getSubImage(int x, y, width, height)` method to crop the image on the rectangle to get the part of the overlay (Image2) you want, then in the second part you use the `Rectangle2D` to fit the image to make sure that it doesn't stretch.
After that you use `g.fill(rect)` to draw the (textured) rectangle onto the output image.

Finally you can do whatever you want with the output image. In the following example I exported it into a `.png` file using `ImageIO`.

**Example:**

> Image1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0Z2k.jpg
> Image2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmiAR.jpg
> Output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgNM2.png

Code:

```
package test;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ImageMasking {

    // Define rectangles
    public static Rectangle2D[] rectangles = new Rectangle[]{
            new Rectangle(0, 0, 350, 50),
            new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 225),
            new Rectangle(0, 175, 350, 50)
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Load images
        BufferedImage image1 = ImageIO.read(new File("image1.jpg"));
        BufferedImage image2 = ImageIO.read(new File("image2.jpg"));

        // Create output file
        File out = new File("out.png");
        if (!out.exists()) {
            if (!out.createNewFile()) {
                throw new IOException("createNewFile() returned false");
            }
        }

        // Create output image
        BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(image1.getWidth(), image1.getHeight(), 
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g = result.createGraphics();

        // Draw image1 onto the result
        g.drawImage(image1, null, 0, 0);

        // Masking
        for (Rectangle2D rect : rectangles){
            // Extract x, y, width and height for easy access in the getSubImage method.
            int x = (int) rect.getX();
            int y = (int) rect.getY();
            int width = (int) rect.getWidth();
            int height = (int) rect.getHeight();
            
            // Setup and draw the rectangle
            TexturePaint paint = new TexturePaint(image2.getSubimage(x,y,width,height), rect);
            g.setPaint(paint);
            g.fill(rect);
        }

        // Export image
        ImageIO.write(result, "PNG", out);
    }
}
```

// Edits ToDo: Create an easy access method for this, but as I am on my phone right now I can't really code.